# HTML5 and QR Code library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qr-code

I was searching for the latest, good one, and secure, library written in HTML5 or JavaScript or jQuery or PHP for reading and creating QR codes.

I know there are 2 methods to read them:

1. Uploading qr code image.
2. Scanning it from web cam.

If it exist, I would like in case 2 to be not FLASH library but HTML5 library.

Any source or link guys?

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625415/how-to-create-qr-code-reader-in-html5-website

Comment: not so much cause i can't user zxing plugin on my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're after, but what about a library like this?

http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

I guess this would serve less on the reading and more on the generating/creating end of things.