# Use smartphone camera from a web app to scan QR code

Tags: android, jquery, html, android-camera, qr-code

I want to build a web app (Html5 + Javascript, NO flash) than, using the smartphone camera, scan a QR code, and sends the result to a server. Is that posible?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, yes it is possible:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625415/how-to-create-qr-code-reader-in-html5-website

hope that helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, yes it is possible:

[How to create a QR code reader in a HTML5 website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625415/how-to-create-qr-code-reader-in-html5-website)

hope that helps.

There would be lots of libraries and examples out on the internet. I would suggest googling it and checking out some open source projects.