# How scann qr code in a web application?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile, qr-code

Hi I would like to scann a Qr code in a PHP web application with a smartphone camera but I don't find how .

I have tried this

http://chris.m0nk3y.net/blog/post/scanning-barcodes-from-your-mobile-web-apps
http://zxing.appspot.com/scan

with this link

```
  zxing://scan/?ret={CODE}&q={CODE}&SCAN_FORMATS=UPC_A,EAN_13
```

But ret={CODE} don't works . How to get to link my QR code remaining in the same window of my browser or what alternative is there?

Comment: This link can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625415/how-to-create-qr-code-reader-in-html5-website

Comment: tanks many to your answer