# Which Document AI processors support Barcode decoding?

Tags: cloud-document-ai

I want to decode some ITF and EAN barcodes from images. I saw that Invoice Parser supports, but the price is a bit too much. Do some of the General processors like Document OCR Processor support barcode?

I could not find the info in the Processors list page https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list

https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference/cloud-document-ai/latest/V1.Barcode
https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#detectedbarcode

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Invoice Parser does support barcode extraction, you can see an example in this sample application:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/document-ai-samples/blob/main/web-app-pix2info-python/README.md#barcodes

However, there's a lot of libraries that support barcode detection if that's all you want to do. Here are some examples:

[Read/decode bar codes from an image in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31443370/read-decode-bar-codes-from-an-image-in-php)

https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-opencv-barcode/

https://blog.aspose.com/barcode/php-barcode-generator-reader-and-scanner-api/